# Elementary books with suggested readings at the end of each chapter

Tags: book-recommendation

I really like how Joseph Gallian in his book, **contemporary abstract algebra**, includes a section of **suggested readings**/references, at the end of each chapter, that points readers to some accessible papers(accessible given the materials covered) .

It is quiet fun to go through the list of suggested readings, as it deepens my understanding of the material, and creating gaps between chapters to allow digestion of the materials.

I'm posting this question, trying to see if I can get a list of books (preferably at the level of first year graduate student) that contains sections of suggested readings (preferably at each chapter or section)

Answer (score 1):

Eleven books published by Cambridge University Press (who seem to encourage this practice):

- Saban Alaca & Kenneth S. Williams, *Introductory Algebraic Number Theory* (2004)
- Alan Baker, *A Comprehensive Course in Number Theory* (2012)
- Bela Bollobas, *Linear Analysis: An Introductory Course* (2nd ed. 1999)
- N. L. Carothers, *Real Analysis* (2000)
- R. M. Dudley, *Real Analysis and Probability* (2002)
- G. Gierz et al., *Continuous Lattices and Domains* (2003)
- J. R. Hindley & J. P. Seldin, *Lambda-Calculus and Combinators: An Introduction* (2008)
- J. H. van Lint & R. M. Wilson, *A Course in Combinatorics* (2nd ed. 2001)
- R. Lidl & H. Niederreiter, *Introduction to Finite Fields and Their Applications* (rev. ed. 1994)
- Michael Spivak, *Calculus* (3rd ed. 1994)
- J. Michael Steele, *The Cauchy-Schwarz Master Class* (MAA / CUP 2004)

(Spivak's and Steele's references for further reading are collected at the end of their books, rather than at the end of each chapter.  Also, there is a fourth edition of Spivak's book, in which the author presumably kept his 1994 promise to update the bibliography, but I haven't seen it.)

Six such books published by Springer:

- Mahima Ranjan Adhikari, *Basic Algebraic Topology and its Applications* (2016)
- William A. Coppel, *Number Theory: An Introduction to Mathematics* (2nd ed. 2009)
- A. L. Dontchev & R. T. Rockafellar, *Implicit Functions and Solution Mappings* (2nd ed. 2014)
- Gerald A. Edgar, *Measure, Topology, and Fractal Geometry* (1990, 2nd ed. 2008)
- Chris Godsil & Gordon Royle, *Algebraic Graph Theory* (2001)
- John Stillwell, *Naive Lie Theory* (2008)

Six such books reprinted by Dover:

- W. E. Deskins, *Abstract Algebra* (Macmillan 1964, 2nd pr. 1966, repr. 1995)
- Steven A. Gaal, *Point Set Topology* (Academic Press 1964, repr. 2009)
- Michael Henle, *A Combinatorial Introduction to Topology* (W. H. Freeman 1979, repr. 1994)
- William J. LeVeque, *Fundamentals of Number Theory* (Addison-Wesley 1977, repr. 1996)
- D. J. A. Welsh, *Matroid Theory* (Academic Press 1976, repr. 2010)
- Steven Willard, *General Topology* (Addison-Wesley 1970, repr. 2004)

Answer (score 1):

(This list is expected to expand from time to time as I working through books)

**The Higher Arithmetic** by H. Davenport

**Topological Spaces: From Distance to Neighborhood** by Gerard Buskes &Arnoud van Rooij